# jQuery.Deferred exception: The string did not match the expected pattern

Tags: safari, syntax-error, jquery-deferred, safari-web-inspector, jquery-3

I've a little headache with this console error, ONLY on Safari (working on MacBook actually).

I have this function:

```
function exists(element){
    var exists = document.querySelector(element);
    return exists;
}
```

invoked inside another function:

```
function includeHoverStylesheet(){
    var path = $("body").attr("data-hover");
    if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement || exists("link[href='" + path + "'"))) {
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet", link.href = path, document.head.appendChild(link) && document.body.removeAttribute("data-hover");
    }
}
```

Now, on Chrome works like a charm, but on Safari the console throw this error:

```
1) Invalid CSS property declaration at: *
2) jQuery.Deferred exception: The string did not match the expected pattern.
3) SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12): The string did not match the expected pattern.
```

Someone have idea what hell happening???

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The string passed to `exists()` has an opening `[` but no `]`, which is enough to cause the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a closing bracket missing, so you are using an invalid selector. (as Roamer-1888 mentioned as comment)

Having a look at the following discussion where invalid selectors in different browsers has been tested, only Safari is that strict bringing up errors:
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5nbmqi/on_handling_invalid_selector_strings/

**For all jquery-Users:** check your jquery version, as there has been bugfixes on selector issues.

I had the same error *only* on Safari on this statement

```
var div = $('<div class="abc">');
```

A statement working fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari when using version jquery 1.11.1; but working fine in all of them with jquery 1.12.4.

In my case I solved it using the following syntax:

```
var div = $('<div>', {"class":"abc"});
```